# Drop table taking too long

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, drop-table

I have a table with approx. 200 million rows (approx. 0.5 TB) and I want to drop it, but it is taking a really long time.

It's been running for 2 days now. I suspect the rollback function to be the reason for this.

Is there a way to avoid the rollback function, so that I can speed this process up? I just want to get rid of the table, because the data in there are of no value any more.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can list the running backends with

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

identify the process trying to rollback something which is working on this table.

Find its `pid`.

You can terminate a backend with the query `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(64738)`, where 64738 is the pid column in your previous `SELECT`.

After that, you can likely DROP that table.

If even that won't work, then restart postgresql, but most likely it will.

Comment: I managed to kill a autovacuum task on the table, and then it dropped the table quick hereafter.

Comment: this answer is the bomb! Thank you!